# Are 301 redirects with hashes supported by all major browsers/proxies these days?

Tags: http, http-status-code-301, http-redirect

I found some info here: [Redirect 301 with hash part (anchor) #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229203/redirect-301-with-hash-part-anchor), but doesn't really answer my question.

I created a SPA that uses Sammy.js for routing based on the URL hash.  Now I have another page on my site (possibly other sites also) that collects some info from the user, then needs to redirect them to my SPA with a specific route.  This other page is ASP.NET 3.5 so I'm using this code, which just does a 301 redirect:

```
Respone.Redirect("/#" + folderID);
```

**It works correctly when I test in Firefox, but I don't currently have access to all major browsers, and also wondering if this will work with most proxies as well -- or will the proxy remove the #hash part from the URL?**

I know the hash part is special and in some cases is client-side only.  For example, I know I can't read the hash value that was set by JavaScript, in something like an ASP.NET postback, form submit, or AJAX request.

However, for this very specific usage where I'm not trying to read it, I'm just trying to set it.. is this widely accepted and robust?  I know basic hyperlinks with hash tags work, even across domains, but of course those are not doing a 301 redirect (are mostly client-side) so not really the same.